# how to compile and run a class in apackage that inherits protected member from another class in another package

Tags: java

this is my first code placed in a directory named certification

```
package certification;
    class Parent{
        protected int x=9;//protected access
    }
```

this is my other code placed in a separate dir named other

```
package other;
    import certification.Parent;
    class Child extends Parent{
    public void testIt(){
    System.out.println("x is" + x);
        }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Child n=new Child();
        n.testIt();
      }
}
```

but the problem is whenever i try to compile the class Child the compiler gives the following error 
Child.java:2: package certification does not exist

```
import certification.Parent;
                ^
```

Child.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol: `class Parent`

```
class Child extends Parent{
                ^
```

Child.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable x
location: `class other.Child`

```
System.out.println("x is" + x);
                        ^
```

please help me rectify it and run it properly.
sincere regards.

Comment: What is the command you are using to compile `Child`? You may have not set the classpath correctly.

Comment: i am using javac Child.java to compile Child @selig

Comment: @user2545332. Compile both your sources as: `javac -d . Parent.java`. Same for *Child.java*.

Comment: @RohitJain should i issue the compile command from the certification directory for Parent class and other directory for the Child command or from the higher directory in which both these directories are placed

Comment: @user2545332. If you are one directory higher than certification directory, run - `javac -d . certification/Parent.java`

Comment: @RohitJain i tried it from the respective directories the Parent class compiles fine but when i try to compile the Child class it gives the same error . HELP ME !!

Comment: @RohitJain the Parent class compiles fine but the problem is with the Child class

Comment: @user2545332 n.voidtestIt();?? are you sure?? it should be n.testIt();

Comment: @Ruchira yeah i have corrected it in the source code. i encountered it while rechechking

Comment: HELP me guys and girls , i face this problem so much working with packages and then i get stuck !!

Comment: Please see the answer I provided, it provides detailed instructions for the same. It should work

Comment: @user2545332 stop crying. Ravi Thapiyal gave a solution that worked but you said there's a runtime error. What is it?

Comment: @PrasadKharkar it worked sir... it was a silly mistake on my part that i was not using java other.Child to run   it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

say your folder strucuture is like this

```
sources/certification/Parent.java
sources/other/Child.java
```

Also, make your `Parent` class as `public` as we are trying to access it outside the package.
Also Child class should be calling `n.testIt()` and not `n.voidTestIt()`. void is the return type.

The classes will be

```
package certification;
   public class Parent{
        protected int x=9;//protected access
    }


package other;
import certification.Parent;
    class Child extends Parent{
    public void testIt(){
    System.out.println("x is" + x);
        }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Child n = new Child();
        n.testIt();
      }
}
```

Follow these steps.

- navigate to `sources` directory using `cd sources`
- Compile `Parent` class first as it is required for `Child` class using command `javac certification/Parent.java`
- Then compile Child class using `javac -classpath . other/Child.java`. Here `-classpath` is the option to tell `javac` command from where to pick the classes requried for `Child.java` and `.` is the current directory which is our classpath i.e. `sources`.
- After compilation is successful, run `Child` class using `java other.Child`. Here we are using fully qualified name for `Child`.

Just navigate to your C drive and do this

```
C:\>cd sources

C:\sources>javac certification/Parent.java

C:\sources>javac -classpath . other/Child.java

C:\sources>java other.Child
x is9

C:\sources>
```

Ideally you should always compile and launch java classes from the room of the directory structure. 
package names in the java files are directory structures. While compiling they are treated as java files so directory structure is used while compiling e.g. `certification/Parent.java`
. But when the classes are compiled, then class files are identified using the package names. So use the fully qualified names from the root directory i.e. the location from where package structure starts. In our example, `sources` is the directory and `certification` and `other` are packages. So the classes shoudl be referred as `certification.Parent` and `other.Child`.

Comment: thank you sir..i found my mistake i was running it with simply java Child and not java other.Child

Answer (score 2):

Followings are need to change;

```
public class Parent{  //parent class should be public
    protected int x=9;//protected access
}
```

and

```
    Child n=new Child();
    n.testIt(); // not m.voidtestIt();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since, the `Child` class is in a different package; the `Parent` class needs to be `public` to become visible for inheritance. Make the `Parent` public as

```
public class Parent {
```

and fix the typo *n.<s>void</s>testIt();* in your `Child#main()` method. Then assuming the following directory structure

```
/src/other/Child.java
/src/certification/Parent.java
```

Compile `Child.java` from inside `/` as

```
/$ javac -cp src -d bin src/other/Child.java
```

This should create the `.class` file at

```
/bin/other/Child.class
```

***EDIT** :*
Once compiled, run from `/` as

```
/$ java -cp bin other.Child
```

Comment: i can compile the class now but the problem is in its running . when i try to run Child class then it shows following error
exception in thread "main" no java.lang.classdeffounderror: child

Comment: @user2545332 Run as `java -cp bin other.Child`. Check update.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to compile Child.java at the root (should be src in many cases) and use a path to compile, something like this assuming from your package name:

```
javac other/Child.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Your classpath should be set up to the parent folder of certification. Normally, you would have an 'src' folder which contains your package structure.

1)cd to 'src' folder.
2)set your classpath at this locations as `SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;.;`
3)compile your Parent as `javac certification\Parent.java`
4)compile your child as `javac other\Child.java`

This should work.

Comment: i tried it bro @adithya the classes are compiling fine but when i ru the class Child it gives the following error
Child.java:2: package certification does not exist
import certification.Parent;
                    ^
Child.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol: class Parent
class Child extends Parent{
                    ^
Child.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable x
location: class other.Child
System.out.println("x is" + x);
                            ^
Child.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method voidtestit()
location: class other.Child
        n.voidtestit();
         ^

Comment: same should be the case while running.

if you are having a 'bin' folder at the same level where you are having the 'src' folder then 

1)cd to 'bin' folder. run your class as java certification.Parent.

Hope this helps.